# Save button stops app

Tags: java, android, save, fileoutputstream, objectoutputstream

```
public void save(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bSave:
            filename = "data/monday.txt";
            vsName.showPrevious();
            vsTime.showPrevious();
            vsQuantity.showPrevious();
            vsImage.showPrevious();
            save.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            try{
                monday = new File(filename);
                if (!monday.exists()) {
                    if (!monday.createNewFile()) {
                        throw new IOException("Unable to create file");
                    }
                }

                fos = new FileOutputStream(monday);
                oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                oos.writeObject(etName.getText().toString());
                oos.writeObject(etQuantity.getText().toString());
                oos.writeObject(etTime.getText().toString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{
                try {
                    fos.close();
                    oos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            break;
    }
}
```

That's the code for my save method. I want it to save the edittext so my textviews will stay even after i close the program. This is my first time using the fileoutputstreams so i don't know how to fix the problem. When i click the save button, it says unfortunately it has stopped.

```
05-22 15:32:40.095: E/AndroidRuntime(6984): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-22 15:32:40.095: E/AndroidRuntime(6984): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not     execute method of the activity
05-22 15:32:40.095: E/AndroidRuntime(6984):     at  android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3599)
05-22 15:32:40.095: E/AndroidRuntime(6984):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
05-22 15:32:40.095: E/AndroidRuntime(6984):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
05-22 15:32:40.095: E/AndroidRuntime(6984):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-22 15:32:40.095: E/AndroidRuntime(6984):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-22 15:32:40.095: E/AndroidRuntime(6984):     at  android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-22 15:32:40.095: E/AndroidRuntime(6984):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-22 15:32:40.095: E/AndroidRuntime(6984):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-22 15:32:40.095: E/AndroidRuntime(6984):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-22 15:32:40.095: E/AndroidRuntime(6984):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-22 15:32:40.095: E/AndroidRuntime(6984):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-22 15:32:40.095: E/AndroidRuntime(6984):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-22 15:32:40.095: E/AndroidRuntime(6984): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-22 15:32:40.095: E/AndroidRuntime(6984):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-22 15:32:40.095: E/AndroidRuntime(6984):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-22 15:32:40.095: E/AndroidRuntime(6984):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
05-22 15:32:40.095: E/AndroidRuntime(6984):     ... 11 more
05-22 15:32:40.095: E/AndroidRuntime(6984): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-22 15:32:40.095: E/AndroidRuntime(6984):     at tbjsoft.medicationreminder.Monday.save(Monday.java:170)
05-22 15:32:40.095: E/AndroidRuntime(6984):     ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 0):

you better use shared preferences to save the text in edittext.

[How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

the method you show here is no help to solve the problem unless you place the code in which you use this method.

Comment: Yeah, i've switched it since then. Now i'm having a problem when I hit the back button, or close the app. The values for the textviews don't stay.

Comment: I actually just figured out how to, but do you know if i can use sharedpreferneces to save images?

Comment: "prefs.edit().put" when you type this you will get some suggestions from android. For now only those are the available options to save preferences. You better cache the images.